# C# How do I use a method in a different class

Tags: c#, class, methods, user-input

Newbie here,
So I need to let the user input the length and diameter of the log also I need to use a method for it and use that method in a different class. I think I got the user input part right, but when I try to use the method it tells me that "The name 'Take' does not exist in the current context". How do I fix this?

```
 Using System;
 namespace Logger
{
class Loggers
{
    private double LogsLength, LogsDiameter; //must be private
    public Loggers(double LogsLengthValue, double LogsDiameterValue)
    {
        LogsLength = LogsLengthValue;
        LogsDiameter = LogsDiameterValue;
    }
    public double TakeLogsLength() { return LogsLength; }
    public double TakeLogsDiameter() { return LogsDiameter; }
    static void PlaceValues(double LogsLengthValue, double LogsDiameterValue)
    {
        Loggers r;
        r = new Loggers(LogsLengthValue, LogsDiameterValue);
        Console.Write("Input the logs length in meters: ");
        LogsLengthValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\nInput logs diameter in centimeters: ");
        LogsDiameterValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PlaceValues(LogsLengthValue, LogsDiameterValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to make class and method public. And you have to add the class name, if you want to use the method without creating an object first OR you have to create an object first and use the object name to use the method. change `class Loggers` to `public class Loggers`. Change `static void PlaceValues...` to `public static void PlacesValues...`. Change `PlacesValues(LogLengthValue...` to `Loggers.PlaceValues(LogLengthValue...`. But i think, there is a lot of more wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

just a wild guess about what you really wanted to do. But I am not sure.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    namespace Logger
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                UserInput.PlaceValues();
            }
        }

        public class UserInput
        {
            public static void PlaceValues()
            {
                Console.Write("Input the logs length in meters: ");
                var logsLength = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\nInput logs diameter in centimeters: ");
                var logsDiameter = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                var loggers      = new Loggers(logsLength, logsDiameter);

            }
        }

        public class Loggers
        {
            private double _logsLength;
            private double _logsDiameter; //must be private

            public Loggers(double logsLength, double logsDiameter)
            {
                _logsLength   = logsLength;
                _logsDiameter = logsDiameter;
            }

            public double GetLogsLength()
            {
                return _logsLength;
            }

            public double GetLogsDiameter()
            {
                return _logsDiameter;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the class and method public to be reachable.
if you want to [read more about access modifiers](http://csharp.net-informations.com/language/csharp-access-specifiers.htm#:%7E:text=public%20is%20the%20most%20common,another%20assembly%20that%20references%20it.)

So your code should look like this:

```
using System;
namespace Logger
{
    public class Loggers
    {
        private double LogsLength, LogsDiameter; //must be private
        public Loggers(double LogsLengthValue, double LogsDiameterValue)
        {
        LogsLength = LogsLengthValue;
        LogsDiameter = LogsDiameterValue;
        }
        public double TakeLogsLength() { return LogsLength; }
        public double TakeLogsDiameter() { return LogsDiameter; }
        public static void PlaceValues(double LogsLengthValue, double LogsDiameterValue)
        {
            Loggers r;
            r = new Loggers(LogsLengthValue, LogsDiameterValue);
            Console.Write("Input the logs length in meters: ");
            LogsLengthValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\nInput logs diameter in centimeters: ");
            LogsDiameterValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Loggers.PlaceValues(LogsLengthValue, LogsDiameterValue);
        }
    }
}
```